# cx_Oracle ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am trying to run a statement with cx_Oracle and I keep getting the issue where it says that the SQL Command not properly ended but after reading documentation It seems that this is correct, but in reality it is incorrect. `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended`

```
vary = "'Y'"
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(hostName, port,
                            service_name=serviceName) 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=usr, password=__pswrd,
                         dsn=dsn_tns) 

c = conn.cursor()  

tempCheck = "'%{0}/%'".format(checkerAR)
statmentApp = 'SELECT TITLE,APP_URL from SOME.DATABASE' \
              'WHERE UPPER(APP_URL) LIKE UPPER(:tc)' \
              'AND ACTIVE_FLAG = :y'
c.execute(statmentApp,tc = tempCheck , y = vary)
```

At the `c.execute` line is where the error gets flagged. I am trying to enter in `tempCheck` into the statement because I want to add wildcards to the SQL statement.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (statmentApp)
```

gives:

```
SELECT TITLE,APP_URL from SOME.DATABASEWHERE UPPER(APP_URL) LIKE UPPER(:tc)AND ACTIVE_FLAG = :y
```

showing that the string concatenation worked too well.  To retain necessary whitespace you'll find it easier to use triple quotes:

```
statmentApp = """SELECT TITLE,APP_URL from SOME.DATABASE
                 WHERE UPPER(APP_URL) LIKE UPPER(:tc)
                 AND ACTIVE_FLAG = :y"""
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm.